# SilverStripe - Update one admin model when another is given new entries

Tags: php, silverstripe

In SilverStripe I have two admin models: Services and Locations. Locations is a list of locations. Services is a list of services that can be provided by these locations. However, only certain locations can offer certain services. What I want to do is, whenever a new Location is added (or if one is removed or renamed), I want to add it to a checkbox field under each service (this way, the content managers can easily control which services are offered where at any time).

Here is the Services data object code (note: I have not added in the checkbox fields yet):

```
class Services extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'varchar',
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
    );

}
```

Here is the Locations data object code:

```
class Locations extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'varchar',
        'AcceptingAppointments' => 'boolean',
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
        'AcceptingAppointments' => 'Accepting Appointments?',
    );

    public function AcceptingAppointments() {
        return ($this->AcceptingAppointments==true ? 'Yes':'No');
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine so far. I can add, edit and delete locations and services. However, I do not know how to approach coding Services so that each service is updated with a complete list of all locations whenever a content manager adds, removes or renames a location entry.

Would using a `$has_many` relationship work in this aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is needed is a `$many_many` relationship between `Service` and `Location`. We want a many to many relationship as a service can have many locations and a location can have many services. To learn more about using `$many_many` relationships have a read of [this lesson](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-many-many) or [this documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/model/relations/#many-many).

Once we have a `$many_many` relationship defined we can then add a [`CheckboxSetField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-CheckboxSetField.html) to control this relationship.

Note, I have renamed the `Locations` class to `Location` and `Services` to `Service` as I think the class name should be singular.

**Service**

```
class Service extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Locations' => 'Location'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title'
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Locations', CheckboxSetField::create(
                'Locations', 
                'Locations', 
                Location::get()->map()
            ));
        }

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

On `Location` we add a `$belongs_many_many` relationship back to `Service` so we can control this relationship on both sides.

**Location**

```
class Location extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'AcceptingAppointments' => 'Boolean'
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'Services' => 'Service'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name',
        'AcceptingAppointmentsNice'
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
        'AcceptingAppointmentsNice' => 'Accepting Appointments?'
    );

    public function AcceptingAppointmentsNice() {
        return $this->AcceptingAppointments ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Services', CheckboxSetField::create(
                'Services', 
                'Services', 
                Service::get()->map()
            ));
        }
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

An alternative to `CheckboxSetField` is the [`ListboxField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-ListboxField.html). The `ListboxField` is a neat dropdown multiselect field. It is useful if the list of options is very long.

```
class Service extends DataObject {

    // ...

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Locations', ListboxField::create(
                'Locations', 
                'Locations', 
                Location::get()->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray(),
                array(),
                null,
                true
            ));
        }

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Also please note, `$summary_fields` must be declared as a `private` variable, not a `public` variable.

Comment: Wow...that is perfect! Thank you so much for that answer--it answered my exact questions, confirmed some ideas I had, and seems to have gotten everything set up the way I wanted.